# Are there any graphical depictions of the iOS 4.0 application life cycle?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to understand the life cycle of an iPhone application.  Are there any graphical representations of this life cycle out there?

Comment: Do you want to know the life cycle as far as the running of the app or the development?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/) is a nice graphical presentation of iPhone app life cycle...

Answer (score 1):

Watch the [WWDC 2010 video sessions](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) 105 and 109: Adopting Multitasking on iPhone OS, Parts 1 and 2.  The iOS 4.0 application life cycle is displayed several times in those presentations and is described in detail.

See also the "[Application Life Cycle](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW17)" section of the [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1).