# What does didFinishLaunchingWithOptions do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What does didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` do and when should it be invoked?.

Also, I am looking for a diagram like the "Activity Life cycle" diagram in Android. If you know please share.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any graphical depictions of the iOS 4.0 application life cycle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321867/are-there-any-graphical-depictions-of-the-ios-4-0-application-life-cycle)

Answer (score 2):

The app delegate is equal to the application delegate in Android and the view lifecycle callbacks equals the Activity lifecycle callbacks.

*(You may have to scroll some of the page though)*

Here are the lifecycle for views: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html

Here are the lifecycle for application (app delegate): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html

Comment: @BP Developer :Thanks for your info

Answer (score 0):

For lifecycle:

For delegate methods call:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/

for detailed delegate messaging (from apple)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: If this has solved the problem there is option to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By the way just a WARNING.

If you are planning to do some remote connection ( api call ) or hard calculation in that method just don't.

Because for responsiveness issues iOS only gives a limited amount of time to every application to finish `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (like ten seconds) if you do not return. Than it will just kill your application

Comment: Hi Ugur! I know it has been a while since you replied to this thread, but I am struggling here. If I shouldn't call an API and do some remote connection, in the didFinishLaunching method. Then where should i make it? I need to call an API to fill some core information which is used all around the app.